# VS Code - WSL - Node debug breakpoints not pausing code execution

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm using VS Code in Windows with WSL.  I have the WSL extension installed, and in VS Code Preferences > Settings I have Node: Auto Attach "on" set.

I can run my program in the VS Code terminal fine, and when I run them with the inspect param like `node --inspect myprogram.js` it says "Debugger attached" and in the VS Code window "Auto Attach: On" is displayed.  However, execution is not being stopped at the breakpoints I have set in the VS Code UI (I made sure because I have breakpoints on some console.log()s that are being printed).

I have also tried using a launch.json debug configuration file but have had less luck with that.  Your thoughts?  Thanks for takin a look.

Comment: did you ever fix this? I have the same issue